# exception in creating directory

Tags: php, directory

Am a beginner in php. My problem is, i use the following code to create a directory and copy some files into it(I used a code get from so itself). The code works fine directory is created and files are copied. But I am getting a warning like this.

```
function copyr($source, $dest) 
{ 
    // Simple copy for a file 
    if (is_file($source)) {
        chmod($dest, 0777);
        return copy($source, $dest); 
    } 

    // Make destination directory 
    if (!is_dir($dest)) { 
        mkdir($dest); 
    }

    chmod($dest, 0777);

    // Loop through the folder 
    $dir = dir($source); 
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) { 
        // Skip pointers 
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') { 
            continue; 
        } 

        // Deep copy directories 
        if ($dest !== "$source/$entry") { 
            copyr("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry"); 
        } 
    } 

    // Clean up 
    $dir->close(); 
    return true; 
} 

copyr("agentSourcefolder", "testTemp5");
```

.

```
Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /home/websiteName/public_html/php_file_upload2.php on line 9
```

I have to get the response from server after this, what should i do? I used

```
header("Location: http://www.websiteName.com/");
```

But it shows the following error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/websiteName/public_html/php_file_upload2.php:9) in /home/websiteName/public_html/php_file_upload2.php on line 41
```

And if the directory is already created this code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/websiteName/public_html/php_file_upload2.php:9) in /home/websiteName/public_html/php_file_upload2.php on line 41
```

is because you are passing the `header('location:')` call after anything has been written to the screen. All of this processing should be done before anything is written to the page, like echo, breaking out of php, etc. Also make sure there's NO white space before the opening `<?php` line.

The other error is likely because a file you're trying to chmod doesn't exist or exist yet. Or that you may need to provide an absolute path to mkdir. like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path-to-new-dir/"`

Comment: is there any way to hide this warning "Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]", if its not appearing in my page it works fine, the directory is also created successfully and the files are copied.

Comment: ok i get it "ini_set( "display_errors", 0);", thanks for your advice

Comment: another option is to suppress with @ like @mkdir() but this is a toss up. ini will hide all errors and maybe you want them so you know what's going wrong. I tend to prefer fixing the errors over hiding them. There's always an answer.